# Android Opencv Submat null object reference

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect a color of a static image using the algorithm from color blob detection from android opencv.

I have a problem around the submat() area but I have installed the opencv correctly. Getting this error:
PS: mRgba is declared as Mat

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.opencv.core.Mat org.opencv.core.Mat.submat(org.opencv.core.Rect)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.example.backup.contour_image.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:103)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9406)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2257)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2257)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2257)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2668)
                                                                                      at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2257)
```

---

My code

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    //mDetector = new ColorBlobDetector();
    Bitmap bm =((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    Mat touchedRegionHsv = new Mat();
    Log.e(TAG,"Touched!");
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bm,touchedRegionHsv,true);

    Scalar lower = new Scalar(22,255,255);
    Scalar upper = new Scalar(38,100,100);

    Rect roi = new Rect();

    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();

    roi.x = (x>4) ? x-4 : 0;                         
    roi.y = (y>4) ? y-4 : 0;

    roi.width = 8;
    roi.height = 8;

    Mat touchedRegionRgba = mRgba.submat(roi);    //<--------------- line of error
    Mat touchedRegionRgba_clone = touchedRegionRgba.clone();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(touchedRegionRgba,touchedRegionHsv,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);
    Core.inRange(touchedRegionHsv,lower,upper,touchedRegionRgba_clone);

    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat heirarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(touchedRegionRgba_clone,contours,heirarchy,Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your mRgba variable is null :) where is it?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention mRgba. mRgba is declared as public outside this method, it's Mat().

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `mRgba` is `null` before `mRgba.submit()`.